# Create automatic code

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to create automatic code example:

`B001, B002, B003, B004 .....`

I have create the function for that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AUTO_CODE()
RETURNS CHAR (4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KODE CHAR(4)
    SELECT @KODE = COUNT (KODE_BARANG)FROM BARANG
    IF @KODE>0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @KODE = RIGHT(KODE_BARANG,4) FROM BARANG
        SET @KODE = @KODE+1
    END
    ELSE SET @KODE=1
    RETURN 'B' + LEFT('00',3-LEN(@KODE))+(@KODE)
END
```

The function above only works for `B001` through `B010`, beyond that it was back to `B001`. It won't work for `B011`, `B012` or `B120`.

After that I have try to do with `if else`:

```
...
DECLARE KODENYA CHAR (5)
IF @KODE >= 0 AND @KODE <=9
    BEGIN
        SET @KODENYA = 'B' + LEFT('00',4-LEN(@KODE))+(@KODE)
    END
    ELSE IF @KODE >= 10 AND @KODE <=99
    BEGIN
        SET @KODENYA = 'B' + LEFT('0',4-LEN(@KODE))+(@KODE)
    END
    ELSE IF @KODE >= 100 AND @KODE <=999
    BEGIN
        SET @KODENYA = 'B' + LEFT('',4-LEN(@KODE))+(@KODE)
    END

    RETURN @KODENYA
```

The result is still the same and somehow I get `@KODE` if it was beyond `9` it return to `null` and `SQL SERVER` read it as `0`.

Is there another way to create this kind of code in `SQL SERVER`?

Comment: change it to "case when " with len

Comment: 'B'+Case LEN(@KODE) when 1 then '00' when 2 then '0' when 3 then '' end+@KODE

Comment: I'd usually recommend just *storing* the numeric portion, and leave the addition of the `B` and formatting as either entirely an application concern or just in a computed column. Don't deliberately *store* this formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for multiple if/case just simple `FORMAT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(KODE INT);
INSERT INTO #tab(KODE) VALUES (1),(2),(10),(99),(101),(100),(999);

SELECT FORMAT(KODE, 'B00#')
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415277)**</kbd>

You can easily tweak it for longer codes by changing format string `'B000#'`

And in your case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AUTO_CODE]()
   RETURNS CHAR(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KODE INT = (SELECT COUNT(KODE_BARANG)FROM BARANG);

    RETURN FORMAT(@KODE, 'B00#');
END
```

*Warning:*

You function may return duplicates/create gaps when many concurrent calls occur.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bdf8b/1/0)**</kbd>

---

Depending on your needs you may consider adding calculated column to your `BARANG` table:

```
CREATE TABLE BARANG(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                   col2 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
                   ...
                   KODE AS (FORMAT(ID, 'B00#'))
);
```